# ES6 [Symbol.iterator] is not a function with an array

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to test this redux saga generator which executes as expected  :

```
export function* mygen(id) {
  let selectedItems = yield select(myselector) //return an array of integer
  for(let item of selectedItems) {
    const {response, error} = yield call(asynFunc, id, item)
    if (response) {
      yield put({type: ACTION_SUCCESS, data: response.data})
    }
    else {
      yield put({type: ACTION_FAILURE, error: error.response.data.error})
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my test :

```
it("myTest", () => {
    const gen = mygen()
    expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(select(myselector))

    expect(gen.next({selectedItems: [1], item:1, id:1})).to.deep.equal(call(asynFunc, 1, 1))
```

})

and I'm having this error :

```
 TypeError: selectedItems[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

which is weird because selectedItems is an array

do you have any idea of how to test it ?
thanks in advance

Comment: You said "selectedItems is an array." _Are you sure_? You set `selectedItems` to the result of a `yield` expression. Yield expressions return `IteratorResult` objects, not arrays. Please check with `typeof`.

Comment: thanks I was doing console log on it and not paying attention that it was an object ;-).  
                         So how would you test it ?

Comment: Have you looked at `selectedItems.value` ?

Comment: As I'm running a test  selectedItems.value returns undefined, but I console logged selectedItems and I have this object     { selectedItems: [ 1 ], item: 1, id: 1 }

Comment: Odd, sorry I'm stuck here. Hopefully someone else can pick this up.

Comment: Any chance you could include the `select` function and the declaration of `myselector`?

Comment: export const myselector = state => state.myreducer.selectedItems

Comment: so, an arrow function returning an array? and what is the `select` function then?

Comment: The select function is from redux-saga

Comment: Now @cyr I don't want to bug you, but you are the one having a problem which needs to be fixed, is there any chance you could add to your question a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example that contains a full running version. If I create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxGqWO?editors=1111), with your code, I get the exact same error, though I don't know what is the select function in your case. From what I see, your state needs to be added somewhere (due to the arrow function), and that state I also don't see anywhere (except in your second call to the generator)

Comment: I've discussed with some colleagues, and the problem seems come from the structure of my loop and the data I'm injecting in my generator during testin. So I think I'll rework it to make it more testable and the problem will be solved

Comment: I've not had success with the `select` function when passing arguments, in the past. It might be best to call `select` without any arguments, then pull the array you need you need out of the entire state. After than you can proceed to iterate over that array.

Comment: are you talking about calling the select without any argument in the test or in the implementation of the saga ?

Answer (score 1):

With small tweaking the test passes:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { call, select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { logger } from '../utils';

const name = '21/Test async function';
const log = logger(name);

const delayTime = 10;

const reducer = () => ({ selectedItems: [ 1 ], item: 1, id: 1 });

const myselector = item => item.selectedItems;

const asynFunc = (id, item) => delay(delayTime,  {response: { selectedItems: [ 1 ], item: item, id: id }});

export function* mygen(id) {
  let selectedItems = yield select(myselector); //return an array of integer
  // log('selectedItems', selectedItems);
  for(let item of selectedItems) {
    // log('item', item);
    const {response, } = yield call(asynFunc, id, item);
    // log('response', response);
  }
}


export default  {
  name,
  saga: () => mygen(1),
  reducer: reducer,
  useThunk: !true,
  execute(store) {
    const gen = mygen();

    const value = gen.next().value;
    log('gen.next().value', value);
    log('select(myselector)', select(myselector));
    log('gen.next().value === select(myselector)', JSON.stringify(value) === JSON.stringify(select(myselector)));

    const selectedItems = [1];
    const response = gen.next(selectedItems).value;
    const asyncCallResult = call(asynFunc, 1, 1);
    log(`gen.next([1]).value`, response);
    log(`call(asynFunc, 1, 1)`, asyncCallResult);
    log(`gen.next([1]).value === call(asynFunc, 1, 1)`, JSON.stringify(asyncCallResult) === JSON.stringify(asyncCallResult));

    return delay(2 * delayTime, this);
  }
};
```

The log looks like:

```
   00000000: [Runner] ---------- running example 21/Test async function
   00000003: [Runner] store initial state Object {selectedItems: Array[1], item: 1, id: 1}
   00000010: [21/Test async function] gen.next().value Object {@@redux-saga/IO: true, SELECT: Object}
   00000011: [21/Test async function] select(myselector) Object {@@redux-saga/IO: true, SELECT: Object}
   00000011: [21/Test async function] gen.next().value === select(myselector) true
   00000012: [21/Test async function] gen.next([1]).value Object {@@redux-saga/IO: true, CALL: Object}
   00000012: [21/Test async function] call(asynFunc, 1, 1) Object {@@redux-saga/IO: true, CALL: Object}
   00000013: [21/Test async function] gen.next([1]).value === call(asynFunc, 1, 1) true
 * 00000088: [Runner] store final state Object {selectedItems: Array[1], item: 1, id: 1}
   00000089: [Runner] ---------- example 21/Test async function is done
```

For the selector `myselector = item => item`, selected items is an object and `TypeError: selectedItems[Symbol.iterator] is not a function` is thrown:

```
case 2:
  selectedItems = _context.sent;
  //return an array of integer
  // log('selectedItems', selectedItems);
  _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
  _didIteratorError = false;
  _iteratorError = undefined;
  _context.prev = 6;
  _iterator = selectedItems[Symbol.iterator](); // selectedItems is not an array
```